# DICOM RetrieveURL tag is empty in JSON output

Tags: c#, dicom, leadtools-sdk

I am using a `DicomDataSet` to add tags and their values as below following:

```
....
var ds = new DicomDataSet();
ds.Initialize(DicomClassType.StudyRootQueryStudy, DicomDataSetInitializeFlags.None);
ds.InsertElementAndSetValue(DicomTag.QueryRetrieveLevel, "STUDY"); 
ds.InsertElementAndSetValue(DicomTag.SpecificCharacterSet, "ISO_IR192");  
ds.InsertElementAndSetValue(DicomTag.RetrieveURL,  "http://localhost/Service/api/wado-rs/studies/" + row.StudyInstanceUID); 
....
```

when I make `json` per `ds` I don't see value for `00081190` like `json` in [this link.](https://www.dicomstandard.org/dicomweb/dicomweb-examples/)

making `json` file snipped code:

```
string jsonFileNameOut = Path.Combine(@"C:\Study", $"{DateTime.Now.Ticks}.json"); 
// Save as JSON with no binary data 
// For the demo, keep the json output file size small by skipping the pixel data 
const DicomDataSetSaveJsonFlags jsonFlags = DicomDataSetSaveJsonFlags.IgnoreBinaryData |
                                            DicomDataSetSaveJsonFlags.TrimWhiteSpace;
ds.SaveJson(jsonFileNameOut, jsonFlags);
```

why `vr`value representation for RetrieveUrl(`81190`) tag is `UN`(unknown), the output is something like below:

```
[{
  "00080005" : { 
   "vr" : "CS", 
   "Value" : [ 
     "ISO_IR 192"
   ] 
   },
  "00080052" : { 
   "vr" : "CS", 
   "Value" : [ 
     "STUDY"
   ] 
   },
  "00081190" : { 
   "vr" : "UN"
   }
  }]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I finally got the solution after reading many articles I decide post the solution here for those that don't know this like me.

So in DICOM protocol there are some private tags that `vr`(Value Representation) for them is `UN` by default after parsing to `json` or `xml` so they won't present in out put.

So we should make private tag to public and set `vr` manually for them like what I do below:

```
DicomElement dm = ds.InsertElement(null, false, DicomTag.RetrieveURL, DicomVRType.UT, false, 1);
if (dm != null)
{
    ds.FreeElementValue(dm); 
    ds.SetStringValue(dm, url, DicomCharacterSetType.UnicodeInUtf8);
}
```

the problem resolved by [`InsertElement`](https://www.leadtools.com/help/leadtools/v19/dh/di/dicomdataset-insertelement.html) and [`SetStringValue`](https://www.leadtools.com/help/leadtools/v19/dh/di/dicomdataset-setstringvalue(dicomelement,string,dicomcharactersettype).html).